# VS Code syntax highlighting for template string css? (Emotion)

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, styled-components, syntax-highlighting, emotion

How do I enable syntax highlighting for emotion `template string css` in VS Code? All the plugins I find are for snippets.

It works with `css({ camelCaseCssProps:...})` but I am trying to use `css variables` for theming without imports and I guess in general I'd rather keep the regular `kebab-case` css syntax in my global styles file:

```
// index.js
    
render(
  <Global
    styles={css`
      html {
        // css variables (and/or camel-case props)
        --color-base: white;
        --color-text: #434449;
       }
    `}
  />
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Install the extension `vscode-styled-components`.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components